# Reading an Array Element as a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to read out the value of the first element in my array.  We can't parse the value out before adding it to the array due to API issues.  What's the easiest way to extract the value from this input element inside the array?

```
myArray: [<input id="@Html.Raw(string.Format("input{0}", i))" type="text" value="@i" maxlength="3">, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The JQuery:

```
var rowData = myArray[0]; //MyArray Created Elsewhere
var firstColumn = rowData[0].val();
arrayOfData[0] = rowData;
```

Comment: I think this might work: `$(myArray[0]).val();`

Comment: No `jQuery` collections are involved based on the snippets you've shown. You can however retrieve the [`<input>`'s own `.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) -- `var firstColumn = rowData[0].value;`

Comment: Tip: Try to create a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Currently, it's not entirely clear how the `myArray`s in each snippet are related, if they're the same object or if `myArray` in the 1st is `rowData` in the 2nd.